# Crash on Setting Delegate

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, delegates

I have a custom view (settingview) with nib and protocol. i want to add this view on a viewcontoller with delegate. When i set its delegate my app crashes and i don't know what i have done wrong.

i don't have NIB for ViewController.

i am attaching few images of my code and View's NIB.

[image: -[UIView setDelegate:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb265e20]

.h

```
@protocol  SettingViewDelegate

@required

-(void)CornerSlider:(id)sender;
-(void)MarginSlider:(id)sender;
-(void)BorderSlider:(id)sender;
-(void)ShadowSlider:(id)sender;
-(void)BorderColor:(id)sender;
-(void)ShadowColor:(id)sender;
-(void)remove:(id)sender;
@end

@interface SettingView : UIView

@property (nonatomic, assign) id  delegate;

-(IBAction)CornerSlider1:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)MarginSlider1:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)BorderSlider1:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)ShadowSlider1:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)BorderColor1:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)ShadowColor1:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)remove1:(id)sender;

@end
```

.m

```
@implementation SettingView


- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        self = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed: @"Setting"
                                          owner: self
                                        options: nil] objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    return self;
}

-(IBAction)CornerSlider1:(id)sender
{
    [self.delegate CornerSlider:sender];
}
-(IBAction)MarginSlider1:(id)sender
{
    [self.delegate MarginSlider:sender];
}
-(IBAction)BorderSlider1:(id)sender
{
    [self.delegate BorderSlider:sender];
}
-(IBAction)ShadowSlider1:(id)sender
{
    [self.delegate ShadowSlider:sender];
}
-(IBAction)BorderColor1:(id)sender{
    [self.delegate BorderColor:sender];
}
-(IBAction)ShadowColor1:(id)sender{
    [self.delegate ShadowColor:sender];
}
-(IBAction)remove1:(id)sender{
    [self.delegate remove:sender];
}


@end
```

[image: Views Nib]

app crashes here after setting its delegate.

```
SettingView *settingView=[[SettingView alloc]init];
[settingView setDelegate:self];
[self.view addSubview:settingView];
```

Comment: write this in SettingsView "@property(nonatomic, assign)id delegate;" it will work

Comment: have u assigned delegate in SettingView?

Comment: Please do not use screenshots of code. It makes editing impossible.

Comment: @Vaibhav Bhai it still not working.

Comment: @anum90 yes i assigned delegate.

Comment: Hm, everything looks ok. You should make sure you are setting the delegate to the SettingView. Place a breakpoint around place where you setDelegate, and check the settingView instance.

Comment: @DobroćudniTapir yes i did. app crashing on line [settingView setDelegate:self]; .

Comment: self.delegate = nil; set this line in viewDidUnload

Comment: @karthi Sorry but its view's subclass, not ViewController.

Comment: I don't think it's related, but you wouldn't get it working in any case if you don't either call the initWithFrame method or override the simple init method to load the view from Nib too

Comment: @micantox its working fine without any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mistake found. It was in IB.
I was setting Custom Class (SettingView) to File's Owner's Class. Now Its View's Custom Class and File's Owner is UIView's Class.

[image]

and now its working fine.  [image].

Answer (score 3):

Replace @required with @optional

```
@protocol  SettingViewDelegate

@optional 

-(void)CornerSlider:(id)sender;
-(void)MarginSlider:(id)sender;
-(void)BorderSlider:(id)sender;
-(void)ShadowSlider:(id)sender;
-(void)BorderColor:(id)sender;
-(void)ShadowColor:(id)sender;
-(void)remove:(id)sender;
@end
```

Comment: i want these as Required.

Comment: @HarvantS. Then you must have to define those method in .m file and have to declare in .h file

Comment: yes they are defined in .m file. and i don't think protocol methods needs to declare in .h file. are they? 

b'cos they are already declared in my protocol.

Comment: @HarvantS. If you have any doubt please read https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithProtocols/WorkingwithProtocols.html :)

Comment: "By default, all methods declared in a protocol are required methods. This means that any class that conforms
to the protocol must implement those methods."

According to your link the class only needs to implement protocol methods.

Comment: @HarvantS. ok then Enjoy :)

Answer (score 0):

See whether you have implemented all the methods of your delegate into your "self.view" class where you add your "Setting View". Also, see whether you had implemented "SettingsViewDelegate" into the class you add "Setting View" as subview.

For more clarification, look this https://stackoverflow.com/a/12660523/859001

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

```
@interface BlaBlaViewController : UIViewController<SettingsViewDelegate>
```

I saw in your code:

```
-(void)setDelegate:(id)delegate
{
   self.delegate = delegate;
}
```

This would result in an endless loop. You should use the synthesized _ivar for overloading the setter (or leave it out all together).

Answer (score 0):

Use the following setter method for delegate in the SettingsView implementation.

```
-(void)setDelegate:(id)adelegate 
{
    _delegate = adelegate;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

.h

```
@protocol  SettingViewDelegate

-(void)CornerSlider:(id)sender;
-(void)MarginSlider:(id)sender;
-(void)BorderSlider:(id)sender;
-(void)ShadowSlider:(id)sender;
-(void)BorderColor:(id)sender;
-(void)ShadowColor:(id)sender;
-(void)remove:(id)sender;
@end

@interface SettingView : UIView

@property (nonatomic, assign) id  delegate;

-(IBAction)CornerSlider1:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)MarginSlider1:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)BorderSlider1:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)ShadowSlider1:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)BorderColor1:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)ShadowColor1:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)remove1:(id)sender;

@end
```

.m

```
-(IBAction)CornerSlider1:(id)sender
{
    if([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@(CornerSlider:)])
    {
        [self.delegate CornerSlider:sender];
    }
}
-(IBAction)MarginSlider1:(id)sender
{
    if([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@(MarginSlider:)])
    {
        [self.delegate MarginSlider:sender];
    }

}
-(IBAction)BorderSlider1:(id)sender
{
    if([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@(BorderSlider:)])
    {
        [self.delegate BorderSlider:sender];
    }

}
-(IBAction)ShadowSlider1:(id)sender
{
    if([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@(ShadowSlider:)])
    {
        [self.delegate ShadowSlider:sender];
    }

}
-(IBAction)BorderColor1:(id)sender{
    if([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@(BorderColor:)])
    {
        [self.delegate BorderColor:sender];
    }

}
-(IBAction)ShadowColor1:(id)sender{
    if([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@(ShadowColor:)])
    {
        [self.delegate ShadowColor:sender];
    }

}
-(IBAction)remove1:(id)sender{
    if([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@(remove:)])
    {
        [self.delegate remove:sender];
    }

}
```

Comment: The issue was in `.XIB` file. See my answer below.