# How to link an existing view controller with a display

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, xcode6

I created a class called HelloWorld and I would like to link it with a display.

I could code in the HelloWorld class in order to control the behaviour for a specific app page.

However, when I clicked on the identifier inspector, it doesn't show the HelloWorld class at all. I was wondering which process I did it incorrectly?

[image]     [image]

Here is an example:

[image]

Comment: Your custom class should be a `UIView` subclass.

Comment: Read this http://stackoverflow.com/a/18588712/2071323

Comment: As @gabbler mentioned "Helloworld" class should be subclass of `UIVIew`.
You  can write it like HelloWord : UIView

Comment: What is superclass of HelloWorld class? UIView or UIViewController?

Comment: @ZaidPathan It was UIViewController. But now when I changed it to UIView, it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is you are trying to change you ViewController's view's class, not your controller's class.

To do that,

**Step 1:** click on your view controller/Click on Hello World shown in your above image.

**Step 2:** Then try to change class name in interface builder.

That's it.

Answer (score 0):

While creating a class always remember to choose correct class for your subclass. like if you are trying to add class in `UITableViewController` type view than your subclass must be of `UITableViewController`

[image]